# Getting Error in EntityManagerWrapper.getNonTxEMsFromCurrentInvocation(EntityManagerWrapper.java:276)

Tags: ejb, eclipselink

I am having my application deployed in EJBContainer in glassfish server. I am calling one method using Callable and future in session bean, and in this method i'm using EntityManager for some transaction but getting an NullPointerException for whenever any call to EntityManager is there. Below is the error stack trace::

```
 Severe:   java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.getNonTxEMsFromCurrentInvocation(EntityManagerWrapper.java:276)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.getNonTxEMFromCurrentInvocation(EntityManagerWrapper.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper._getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:213)
at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:455)
at LogisticsEngineSessionBean.getAllPackSerialsForProcess(LogisticsEngineSessionBean.java:3137)
at LogisticsEngineSessionBean.processSalesOutLines(LogisticsEngineSessionBean.java:3462)
at LogisticsEngineSessionBean.lambda$updateSKULocationStatusOnSell$0(LogisticsEngineSessionBean.java:2972)
at LogisticsEngineSessionBean$$Lambda$7/1138463255.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1689)
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

Please suggest whether it is because i'm trying to do multi threading or any alternate for this is available. I'm using EclipseLink JPA. This NullPointerException is not within my Code,it is coming in EntityManager which is working fine when i'm not doing MultiThreading. And EntityManager Object is not null, Please read the question properly before giving downvote.

Comment: This has to do with your container not your JPA provider - the EM wrapper isn't null, but the context underneath it is. EntityManagers are not thread safe anyway, so each thread is going to need its own.

Comment: Then what can i do to rectify this, I need this callable functionality for better processing as i'm processing large number of data. What can I do to put transaction context there.